# PHP - regular expression to remove domain name from row

Tags: php, regex

I'm fetching a lot of product rows from the database.

Some of these rows contains a domain name (eg. google.com) which I'd like to be removed (trim) from the string before outputting it. **NOTE: There are multiple TLD's (.se, .fi., .net, .org ...)**

At first, I will fetch all domain names from domain table into own array and then with `preg_match()`, run a test whether the string contains a specific domain or not. If domain is not found from product row, nothing needs to be trimmed.

Here's what the domains array will look like:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [domain] => google.com
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [domain] => google.se
        )
```

Here's an example of rows outputted from the database:

```
Product 1 - Test purposes 1
Product 2 - Test purposes 2 google.com
Product 2 - Test purposes 2 google.se
```

And underneath is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
...
$table = [];

# loop through all rows from the database
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    # loop through all domains
    foreach($domains as $domain) {
        if(preg_match("/{$domain['domain']}/i", $row['product'],$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $trimmed = str_replace($domain['domain'], '', $row['product']) ;
            $table[$i]['product'] = $trimmed;
        } else {
            $table[$i]['product'] = $row['product'];
        }
    }
}
```

This does ignore all the domains it finds and just uses the original `$row['product']` instead of trimming the domain name from the `$row['product']`.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: The regex above doesn't remove the domain name from the `$row['product']`, it returns the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, just set the $multi variable to whatever you are using....

```
// (?) could have more than one domain match true / false

$multi = FALSE;

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch ( ) )
{
    // loop through all domains

    $trimmed = $row['product'];

    foreach ( $domains as $domain )
    {
        if( preg_match ( "/{$domain['domain']}/i", $trimmed ) )
        {
            $trimmed = str_replace ( $domain['domain'], '', $trimmed );

            if ( $multi === FALSE )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $table[$i]['product'] = $trimmed;
}
```

Comment: But one thing about this... I still don't see where you are setting or increasing the variable ($i) in array $table[$i]....

Comment: Accidentally ommited it from the source code. This seems to do the trick, I'll accept this as an answer. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

This is a beautiful one. You're going to love the answer.

Add the following line before the `} else {`:

`continue 2;`

**Explanation**

Since you're doing a double loop, if the domain that is matching is not the last domain, it will override the domain it *did* match. Thus you need to go straight to the next *row*, not just the next *domain* once you've found a match.

**Code**

```
<?php

$domains = [
    ["domain" => "google.com"],
    ["domain" => "google.se"]
];

$rows = [
    ["product" => "Product 1 - Test purposes 1"],
    ["product" => "Product 2 - Test purposes 2 google.com"],
    ["product" => "Product 2 - Test purposes 2 google.se"],
];

$table = [];

# loop through all rows from the database
foreach($rows as $id => $row){
    # loop through all domains
    foreach($domains as $domain) {
        if(preg_match("/{$domain['domain']}/i", $row['product'],$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $trimmed = str_replace($domain['domain'], '', $row['product']) ;
            $table[$id]['product'] = $trimmed;
            continue 2;
            //As soon as you hit a match, go to the next *row*.
            //Don't try to match any more domains.
        } else {
            $table[$id]['product'] = $row['product'];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($table);
```

**Caveats**

This assumes that you only have *one* domain match per row.

https://3v4l.org/Oo2Ie

Comment: but that does nothing to stop multiple }else{ blocks from being run when there is no match, that }else{ in the domain loop needs to moved out of the domain loop and a if() question added after that loop if $trimmed is still empty, ie; no match was found...

Comment: Ya, I would probably restructure the loop also, but `continue 2;` was the least invasive solution.